# Disable subdomain in flow stormcrawler

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

How we can disable inject sub domain in streaming?
Now, if we inject `www.ebay.com` in stream than in out we have subdomain pages: `my.ebay.com`, `community.ebay.com`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure HostURLFilter to exclude URLs which are outside the seeds hostnames, by setting *ignoreOutsideHost* to true in *urlfilters.json*

```
{
  "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.host.HostURLFilter",
  "name": "HostURLFilter",
  "params": {
    "ignoreOutsideHost": true,
    "ignoreOutsideDomain": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed it in file target/classes/urlfilters.json and restarted the stream, but i see the same. I will try to look at source code and debug it...

Comment: change it in src/main/resources and recompile. How do you run the code?

Comment: I think you right! Run: I call "package" in IDEA Intellij and :>> storm jar target/es-mycrawl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.apache.storm.flux.Flux --remote es-crawler.flux

Comment: Thank you Julien Nioche! I should change this json in project resources and compile after once.